# Unexpected Token ":" in Spring @Query Param

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jpa

I have a [Spring Repository @Query](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.at-query) with named parameters in my application:

```
@Query("SELECT p FROM :person")    
Page<Person> find(@Param("table") String table, Pageable pageable);
```

And a Controller to handle the request/query the table (:table)

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/search/{table}", produces="application/json", method = RequestMethod.GET) 
    public Page<Person> searchTables(@PathVariable String table) {
        return Page<Person> list = repo.find(table, new PageRequest(1, 20));
    }
```

The repository and request mapping are working properly so I've omitted those, but am getting the following Exception:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: : near line 1, column 15 [SELECT p FROM :table]
```

According to the Spring docs this is how the `@Query` named params are prefixed with a `:`, so I'm not sure why I am getting this error.

From the docs:

> ...you can use @Param annotation to give a method parameter a concrete
> name and bind the name in the query.

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't think you can bind tables names. AFAIK you can only bind conditional values within a `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Thanks @SotiriosDelimanolis that's what I was thinking; do you know of a "Spring" way to bind tables similar to this method?

Comment: I feel like you're trying to be too generic and too aggressive with DRY.  Just write a different repo implementation for each table.

Comment: I know of NO JDBC drivers that allow a JDBC statement with the table name as PARAMETER. You know of any? Because that is what you're wanting to happen, and all JPA providers will use JDBC

Comment: Easy there, Neily boy

Answer (score 0):

Please, see #{#entityName} 
link(spring-data): http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query.spel-expressions .